# Why is List[str] not a subclass of Sequence[str]

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

`List` is a subclass of `Sequence`:

```
>>> from typing import List, Sequence
>>> issubclass(List, Sequence)
True
```

but `List[str]` is not a subclass of `Sequence[str]`:

```
>>> issubclass(List[str], Sequence[str])
False
```

Why?

Comment: Why should it be? `List[str]` and `Sequence[str]` are like instances; specific forms of the generic type. `list()` is not a subclass of `abc.Sequence()` either.

Comment: Or put it differently: *What use* would an IS-A relationship between `List[str]` and `Sequence[str]` have when annotating?

Answer (score 1):

> What use would an IS-A relationship between `List[str]` and `Sequence[str]` have when annotating?

This is the major point to take away. Checking if a type is a subtype of another type is not generally something you should be doing while type annotating your code. This is generally something that has been noticed and is the reason why there's a debate on [the nuking of `__subclasscheck__`](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/136).

As Mark Shannon [states in a comment](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/136#issuecomment-217386769):

> It is meaningful to check whether a type is a subtype of a type, but that is the job of a static checker and doesn't belong in the typing module.

Either way, the checks are [all made in `GenericMeta`s `__subclasscheck__`](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L1043), the metaclass for generic types

As is, the current implementation is more focused on cases where the container type is similar but their sub-scripted types differ, in this case, checks are made depending on if the sub-scripted types are [covariant or contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). For example, `List` types are neither, as such, checking for a `subtype` relationship with:

```
issubclass(List[bool], List[int])  # checks if bool == int
```

returns false. For sequences, the types are covariant, as such, the following yields `True`:

```
issubclass(Sequence[bool], Sequence[int])  # checks if bool is a subclass of int
```

On the other hand, for types without a specified type (as in your first case):

```
issubclass(List, Sequence)
```

`__subclasscheck__` in `GenericMeta` will [delegate](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L1077) to [`__subclasscheck__` in `ABCMeta`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/abc.py#L194) where it will evaluate to `True`.

Finally, if the two types are different, as in:

```
issubclass(List[str], Sequence[str])
```

and the the base class in the [`issubclass` call is an instance of `GenericMeta`](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L1079), `False` is returned; this condition is satisfied for most of the types in `typing`.

Whatever the case it is worth mentioning that this might not exist in a future release, or, its behaviour might be completely different; the module is still provisional.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.. Your answer is about how the typing module is implemented, which is fine, but it misses the real point, which is why it is implemented this way.